# XML validation against XSD: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'xxx'

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE library SYSTEM "library.dtd">
<library
xmlns="http://example.com/a"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com library.xsd"
name=".NET Developer's Library">
<book>
<category>computerss</category>
<title>Programming Microsoft .NET</title>
<author>Jeff Prosise</author>
<isbn>0-7356-1376-1</isbn>
</book>
<book>
<category>computer</category>
<title>Microsoft .NET for Programmers</title>
<author>Fergal Grimes</author>
<isbn>1-930110-19-7</isbn>
</book>
</library>
```

And the following Java code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
docBuilderFactory.setSchema(sf.newSchema(new File("library.xsd")));
docBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
docBuilder.parse(new FileInputStream("data.xml"));
```

It produces the following error:

`[Error] :7:33: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'library'.`

If I remove the XSD declaration in the XML file everything works fine...

Any inside highly appreciated. Thanks.

And here is the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="library">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="book" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="book">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="category"/>
                <xs:element ref="title"/>
                <xs:element ref="author"/>
                <xs:element ref="isbn"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element  name="category">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="computer" />
            <xs:enumeration value="poetry" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="isbn" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Please post your schema as well

Comment: Done. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: This example might be helpful: http://java-by-ash.blogspot.com/2012/07/xml-schema-validation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML has a reference to namespace (xmlns="http://example.com/a") which is not the same as in your schema. Have you tried to validate your XML against schema in any XML editor (e.g. Altova or Eclipse etc).

So far it looks like your parsing error is legit, XML is not valid according to the schema.

Comment: How should I include the namespace in the XSD file?

Comment: Typically schema definition would look like this: <xs:schema xmlns="http://aaa.com/types/common"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 targetNamespace="http://aaa.com/types/common"
 elementFormDefault="qualified"
 id="CoreSimpleTypes">

Comment: In fact there are three places that should have the same namespace, and tall three are different: the targetNamespace of the schema, the namespace of the root element in the instance document, and the first URI in the xsi:schemaLocation attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema definition is incorrect. For a start, as maximdim says, your schema has no `targetNamespace="http://mysite.com/a"` attribute in the schema tag.

Secondly your schema looks as if it should only have a single root element, yours has 6.

A correct schema for your XML instance would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://mysite.com/a" targetNamespace="http://mysite.com/a">

  <xs:element name="library">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="book" type="book" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="book">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="category">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="computer" />
            <xs:enumeration value="poetry" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="isbn" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: This I don't get "Secondly the schema can only have a single root element, yours has 6."

Comment: OK, what I meant was that from your instance document it was clear you had a root element called "library" which contained one or more "book" complex types. Your schema definition defines book as a root node, not as a complex type.

Comment: It is NOT TRUE that a schema can only define a single root element. It is also NOT TRUE that DTDs are made obsolete by XML Schema - they are still needed, for example, to define entities. Downvoting.

Comment: @MichaelKay thanks for the comment. I was aware that a schema can define more than one root type, have updated my answer to reflect what I meant to say (also in previous comment). Re comments about DTD however, not sure what you mean by "used to define entities"? As far as I, and probably 99% of the worlds development community, is concerned, there is effectively no reason whatsoever to use DTD. Please undo your downvote in light of my recent corrections. PS have only the greatest respect for your knowledge in this area.